# MySQL Calculate Percentage of Total Donations

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a donation site and a little bit stuck on finding what percent of the Donation Goal that the Current Donations are at?

In my MySQLi database I have two columns - `donation_goal` (numerical eg. 500) and `current_raised` (numerical eg. 20.00).

What I need to do is find and display how much in percentage has been raised currently out of the donation goal. So if £10 was donated and the goal was £100 it would display 10%. But it would do this each time the page was loaded.

I display each page with the code below and need to find a way to add this feature to this code below:

```
<?php


$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $page_name = $row['page_name'];
    $count = strlen($page_name);
    if($count < 27){
        $space = '<br> <br/>';
    } else {
        $space = '';
    }
    $page_dp = $row['page_dp'];
    $donation_goal = $row['donation_goal'];
    $current_raised = $row['current_raised'];


?>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="pageimg/<? echo $page_dp; ?>" style="width:348px;height:233px;" alt="Page Image">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><? echo $page_name; ?> <? echo $space; ?></h3>
        <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%">10%
    <span class="sr-only">10% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
</div>
        <p><b>£<? echo $donation_goal; ?>.00</b> Target | <b>£<? echo $current_raised; ?></b> Raised</p>
        Here is a little info about this current topic, please help us raise more than we can! We need your help!
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Donate Now</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Details</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<?
} 
?>
```

I have tried adding this code to the mix, but receiving errors so am pretty sure I have no idea how to add it correctly:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages, COUNT( current_raised ) AS test, concat(round(( current_raised/donation_goal * 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
```

This just gave out errors. Any ideas of how to do this efficiently with short code?

Comment: Everytime it was `10%` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question? Something like `"SELECT page_dp, donation_goal, current_raised,  (current_raised/donation_goal*100) percentage FROM pages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";`? Then you would do like: `<span class="sr-only"><?php print $row['percentage']; ?>% Complete (success)</span>`

Comment: Sample data and desired results -- in a tabular format -- would help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Cyclone - this works well, however the percentage shows up with numbers after the decimal? such as 18.66666666% is there a way to stop this? And just round it?

Comment: Yes you just need to round the result using `ROUND()`. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to calculate the percentage of the dontation from the goal you could do this directly in your query:

```
SELECT page_dp, 
       donation_goal, 
       current_raised, 
       ROUND(current_raised/donation_goal*100) percentage 
FROM pages 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 3
```

Then you only need to output the percentage within your loop:

```
<span class="sr-only"><?php print $row['percentage']; ?>% Complete (success)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT p.*, pc.cr / donation_goal
FROM pages p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(current_raised) as cr FROM pages) pc
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: What would I use to display the donation percentage?

Comment: Isn't that the ratio of the `cr` (the sum of what has been raised so far) to the goal?